# Native Android VPN programmatically

Tags: android, vpn, enterprise, ipsec, xauth

Variants of this question exist, but I can't seem to understand something.

If you read at the end of the features in [ICS / 4.0](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0-highlights.html), there is mention of

> Enterprises can also take advantage of a standard VPN client built into the platform that provides access to L2TP and IPSec protocols.

My assumption here is that since it's not under the "Developer" section, that we didn't get a developer API access other than the VpnService API. I've looked at ToyVPN and this is just useless, since I need a REAL IPSec IKEv1 XAuth connection to connect to enterprise firewalls.

I've found several solutions which require root and [VPNCilla](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.mjm4456.vpncillatrial&hl=en) which apparently doesn't though I haven't been able to successfully have it establish the connection.

Does this mean that there really is no way to PROGRAMMATICALLY create a profile for or connect to an IPSec IKEv1 XAuth gateway/firewall unless we implement the protocol in Java or using the NDK (like StrongSwan did with IKEv2) ?

Answer (score 0):

It's extremely unlikely that there is a way to create a VPN profile without root or system app privileges. You can take a look at how this is implemented in AOSP settings [here](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/tree/master/src/com/android/settings/vpn2).