# android - How to connect to a VPN programmatically that has been manually configured?

Tags: android, connection, vpn, ipsec

### INTRODUCTION

Many questions have been asked about the **configuration** of the VPN connections.
Probably the most famous with its important answer is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444757/how-to-configure-vpn-programatically).
The closest question to my needs is the [following one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900594/native-android-vpn-programmatically).

But I have not found the answer I am looking for yet.

1. I have manually configured a **IPSEC Xauth PSK** connection using the Android native VPN connection section ([example image](https://www.bestvpn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Connected.png)).
2. I have established the connection for the first time to the VPN in order to check the "Save account information" checkbox, so I will always have credential saved without prompt the user to insert it anymore.

### QUESTION

How can I connect programmatically to this VPN connection?

Because I have set everything I need, it's not obligatory to specify any host, username or password during the programmatical connection (because I have already done it manually in the above steps).

Comment: Could you please explain how you managed to create the IPSEC Xauth PSK  connection ?

Comment: @StelianMorariu I must be honest, I don't remember what you are asking for since I have changed my job and I am not working on it yet. What I can say is that I didn't found any solution on it.

Comment: ah, ok. No worries. I was curious how you achieved 1. and 2. from the question